# Proving associativity of binary operation

Tags: group-theory, radicals, binary-operations

If $S = \{x\in\mathbb{R} \mid x>0\}$ with the binary operation $\star$ given by

$$ x\star y = \sqrt{xy} $$

Then to show S is a group we of course need to show $(S,\star)$ satisfies the group axioms, the second of which is the associativity axiom:

(G$2$): For any $a,b,c\in S$, $a\star(b\star c) = (a\star b)\star c$

If we take $x,y,z\in S$ and apply this we get

$$x\star (y\star z) = \sqrt{x\sqrt{yz}} =\sqrt{x}\sqrt{\sqrt{y}} \sqrt{\sqrt{z}}$$

and
$$(x\star y)\star z = \sqrt{z\sqrt{yx}}=\sqrt{z}\sqrt{\sqrt{y}} \sqrt{\sqrt{x}}$$

Am I being obtuse because I don't see how $x\star (y\star z)$ and $(x\star y)\star z$ could be equal here?

Comment: you're right, it's not associative

Comment: I need to stop asking questions here whilst being sleep deprived, the question was asking whether or not they were groups...thank you anyhow